# How can I move a thread from Stack Overflow to DBA Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, migration

Forgive my ignorance, but is it possible to move a question that I have asked in Stack Overflow to https://dba.stackexchange.com/?

Will I require certain level of reputation before I am able to do so?

Comment: At [250 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: Do you mean this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991206/importing-a-different-character-set-export-dump-into-another-db-instance)? Flag for moderator attention.

Comment: If so, that one has no answers or any other content. Just delete it and ask it again.

Comment: @Ben yes that was the question.

Answer (score 3):

Only moderators can move posts unilaterally and can move it to any site, and even then, they almost never do it without checking with a moderator on the target site.

As a regular user, you can't move your post yourself.  You can vote to migrate your own question with 250 rep (or any post with 3K rep), or flag it for migration with less than that.  But as a regular user, the options for migration are limited to 4 sites, plus meta.stackoverflow.

Fortunately, dba.SE is one of the migration paths available from Stack Overflow

> [image: migration options]

So with more than 250 rep, you can vote to migrate, but you need 3 other users to agree with you and vote to migrate it to dba.SE as well.  Just click "close" under your post and select "Off-Topic" and "Belongs on another site"

However, since the post has no answers, deleting and reposting is certainly the fastest option.